# How to call C function from Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, ffmpeg

I'm currently trying to convert videos on iOS using FFmpeg.
I've modified their example in [transcoding.c](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/transcoding.c) according to my needs.

How do I actually call the following function from Objective-C:

```
int mainFunction(int argc, char **argv);
```

I'm not sure on how to provide the arguments from Objective-C.
Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not 100%, but I'm pretty sure you can just call the function as-is-- i.e, `int tempInt = mainFunction(100,&tempChar)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Objective-C is a superset of C. All you need to do is call it from your Objective-C code.

```
 char* args[] = { "foo", "bar", NULL }; // Might need the NULL to emulate command line arguments.
 int result = mainFunction(2, args);
```

You could pass argc and argv directly from your own `main`

```
 int main(int argc, char** argv)
 {
      int result = mainFunction(argc, argv);
 }
```

If your arguments are in an array of NSStrings, you'll need to convert them to a normal C array of C strings:

```
char** cStringArray = malloc(([stringArray count] + 1) * sizeof(char*));
for (int i = 0 ; i < [stringArray count] ; ++i)
{
   NSString* aString = [stringArray objectAtIndex: i];
   cStringArray[i] = [aString UTF8String];
}
cStringArray[[stringArray count]] = NULL;
int result = mainFunction([stringArray count], cStringArray);
free(cStringArray);
```

It's a long time since I last did any Objective-C, so apologies for any syntax errors.

Comment: So just curious, I have only seen `**` with `NSError`, would you mind a quick explanation for `char* args = {...}` being a valid argument?

Comment: @AO it isn't valid, it's a typo

Comment: Hi @JeremyP,

When I use `char* args = { "foo", "bar", NULL };`, Xcode gives me a warning `Excess elements in scalar initializer`. Any idea why it gives me that warning?

Comment: @martisan Because it is wrong. There was a typo in my answer which I corrected. It should be `char* args[] = { "foo", "bar", NULL };`